# Why is types.BuiltinFunctionType the same as BuiltinMethodType even though there's clearly a difference between functions and methods?

Tags: python, function, methods

Since [`types.BuiltinFunctionType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.BuiltinFunctionType) is exactly the same thing as [`types.BuiltinMethodType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.BuiltinMethodType):

```
>>> import types
>>> types.BuiltinFunctionType is types.BuiltinMethodType
True
```

it isn't possible to distinguish functions from methods that are implemented in C:

```
>>> isinstance(sorted, types.BuiltinMethodType)
True
>>> isinstance(int.from_bytes, types.BuiltinFunctionType)
True
```

And yet, python clearly knows that `sorted` is a function, and `int.from_bytes` is a method, which we can see in their `repr`:

```
>>> sorted
<built-in function sorted>
>>> int.from_bytes
<built-in method from_bytes of type object at 0x7fded4c9d860>
```

Why, then, are `BuiltinFunctionType` and `BuiltinMethodType` the same thing? Is there or isn't there a difference between functions and methods defined in C?